# Not able to run python file which is under django project

Tags: python, django

I have my project tree like .

```
├── sizer
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── node
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── node_serializer.py
│   │   ├── node_serializer.pyc
│   │   ├── part_serializer.py
│   │   ├── part_serializer.pyc
│   │   ├── Part_Serializer.pyc
│   │   ├── test.py
│   │   ├── test.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── tests.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── requirement.txt
│   ├── sizer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│   ├── solver
│   │   ├── attrib.py
│   │   ├── attrib.pyc
│   │   ├── cap.py
│   │   ├── cap.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── node.py
│   │   ├── node.pyc
│   │   ├── nodes1.json
│   │   ├── nodes2.json
│   │   ├── parts.json 
│   ├── strings.py
│   ├── strings.pyc
│   └── workload
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── models.pyc
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── tests.pyc
│       ├── urls.py
│       ├── urls.pyc
│       ├── views.py
│       └── views.pyc
```

I have created `node` and `workload` app by `manage.py startapp` command .

In the above directory structure I copied `solver` .Now I am  importing my node.model under sizer.py file like .

```
import json
from pulp import *

from attrib import *
from cap import *
from node import *
from wl import *
from sizer.node.models import Part,Node
```

When I run python `solver/sizer.py` I am keep on getting

```
ImportError: No module named node.models
```

Please help me out what might I am doing wrong here .Spent more then 4 hours still not able to figure out .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your app name is `node` then your import statement should look like:

```
from node.models import Part, Node
```

Note that this requires that you already included `node` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: I tried it already if you see there is already node module available under solver package also

Comment: There is a `node` **package** under the main project `sizer` _and_ a `node` **module** under the app `solver`. They are separate things.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why an import might fail.

1. The module is not on the path. To check this print sys.path in your script just before you import the module.
2. The module is broken and cannot be imported. You can check this by opening a Python console in the same directory as the module and attempting to import. Does that work?
3. Importing the module results in a CIRCULAR import. This means that the import imports another module that imports another module that imports the original module. This is easy enough to avoid with a little thought and a clear hierarchy.

So, which problem do you have? I have no idea because I can't see the sys.path, and I can't see the code in your files.

What I can see is a bit of a mess. You have multiple modules named 'node'. You have manage.py files at multiple levels. You've included the .pyc files in the output instead of editing them out for the reader. You have so many different modules called 'node', 'sizer' or 'solver' that it must be VERY confusing to figure out which one is being imported at any given time.

Your underlying problem might be that you are trying to work on a project without using source control (git) which means you don't know what changes broke things and you don't feel brave about making big changes because you have no way of stepping back in time if they don't work out.